# How to get the dynamic data from one page into another page using thyme leaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to get the information(which is dynamically generated) from one html page into another html page.

I used a tag th:fragment in first html page
and th:include in second  html page.

But i am getting only static content of first page, it is possible to get the dynamic data or not?can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
@RequestMapping("/Menubar")
public String Ajax(Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {
    List l2 = new ArrayList();

    List l = menuService.listMenus();
    Iterator i = l.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        String s = (String) i.next();
        System.out.println(s);

        List submenu = menuService.getSubMenu(s);

        System.out.println(submenu
                + "sub menuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu");

        menu m = new menu();
        m.setS(s);
        m.setL(submenu);
        l2.add(m);

    }
    HttpSession hs = req.getSession();
    hs.setAttribute("lokesh", l2);


    System.out.println(l2);
    return "Menubar";

}

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String hom(Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {


    return "test";

}
```

Comment: It's possible but let's see your code so we can help.

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes it's possible.But if you need any help on this then you have to show us what you have done so far.

Comment: NO,i have Solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

th:include will pull and render whatever the th:fragment encompases.

e.g.

```
    <div th:fragment="show_data">
<p>Hello Data<p>
<p><span th:text="${somedata}></span></p>
    </div>
```

the render will result in following being passed to the controller method:

```
<p>Hello Data<p>
<p><span th:text="${somedata}></span></p>
```

If the th:fragment contains variables e.g. ${somedata} which you want rendered on your main page, you must remember to pass that same variable to your main page otherwise it won't get rendered.

e.g.

```
public String main(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("somedata", "this is test data.");
return "main";
}
```

will result in render of:

```
// main page content
This is main page data.
// fragment content
Hello Data
this is test data
//continuation of main page content
blah blah blah
```

Comment: Ok i suggest uploading your code into the question to assist others and help find the right answer